# Dynamically change cursor color in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, cursor

My question is - How to change color of cursor in EditText more then one time.

I have editText and two btn for change color of cursor

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        editText.setText(Html.fromHtml("5+6+3<sup>2</sup>+6"));
    }

    public void btn1(View v){
        try {
            Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(editText, R.drawable.cursor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ALERT", "exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.e("ALERT", "exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        editText.invalidate();

    }

    public void btn2(View v){
        try {
            Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(editText, R.drawable.cursor_exponent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ALERT", "exception: " + e.getMessage());
            Log.e("ALERT", "exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        editText.invalidate();
    }
}
```

When I start app and press btn1, color change happens.

But after, when I press btn2 color does not change.

If I close app, and start again, and then I Press btn2 and color changes.

But after, if I press btn1, color does not change.

How to fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATED**

I updated the code in a question

1.1. Used different Field f

1.2. I need use the same EditText becouse this btn must change cursor in a same edittext

2. For what i need use View v?
3. Yes, its my mistake

I added showing Log in catch but nothing inside had

And i used a public field

It not fixed my issue, have any different idea?

**UPDATED 2**

Maulik Panchal thanks for the help.
It work.
I'm sorry I didn't notice that in your last code you use "if" for deny second change color.

But now i see your code and i have a few question.

You use "`editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(...);`" for change background color.

I want change cursor color, and i looked and not find option in editText for change cursor color.

And if i use my old part code for change cursor color its work only in first time

```
try {
    Field f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    f.set(editText, R.drawable.cursor_exponent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ALERT", "exception: " + e.getMessage());
    Log.e("ALERT", "exception: " + e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to exactly change color of cursor?

Thanks

Comment: When you press anyone of the button, it is going at `catch()` can you post the log please?

Comment: you  are using a private field of EditText, this is not recommanded... Are your calling invalidate on editText? try to call invalidate after  changing the drawable.

Comment: i updated the question can you check please. thanks

Answer (score 0):

(I updated your question to be more clear).

You did some mistakes:

- you use the same Field f and EditText editText, for both btn1 and btn2
- you never use the parameter View v ?
- you had duplicate source line codes (edited)

Try to adapt that, and let us know if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Great Work... :)

Answer (score 0):

i tried to solve your problem as per below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editText;
    Button btnRed, btnGreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.et);
        btnGreen = findViewById(R.id.green);
        btnRed = findViewById(R.id.red);
        btnRed.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnGreen.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.red:
                    editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); 
                break;
            case R.id.green:
                    editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);  
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

Solution for Update2:-

You can change your cursor and underline below your text by below code..

First of all make one style in your style.xml section:

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">your color</item>
    </style>
```

after this just Add this line in your EditText:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
```

This is your solutions..Thank you:)

Comment: it work for you? because for me not, the same problem,  button is working that was pressed first

Comment: u want to change for everytime color change on button click?i supposed that u want only color change of button click.thats why i uploaded it.

Comment: I want press btn1 and changes color of cursor.
And after i want press btn2 and change to another color.
And after i want again press btn1 etc...
But now only working btn that was pressed first.
How fix it?
Thanks

Comment: i updated my code.from this code you can change color of cursor after every click of button.Thank you.

Comment: hie, thanks to you, can you watch my "Updated 2" in question and help me with this